# Is $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ the automorphism group of the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms, analytic-functions, automorphism-group

Let $f:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}$ be any analytic automorphism of the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\text{Im}z>0\}$. Then can it be written by the form
$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
for which $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{R}$ with $ad-bc=1$?

**Motivation of this problem.** I am reading Seere's [A Course in Arithmetric](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Ejlipman/MA598/Serre-Course%20in%20Arithmetic.pdf). In the page 77, I think that what he is saying "...it is the group of all analytic automorphism of H.", to summarize, is
$$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})=\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R}).$$
It is clear that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})\supset \text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R}),$ but I can not understand the reason why the converse inclusion is also true.

**My Attempt.** I have already known the following statement:

> **Theorem.** The only analytic automorphisms $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are the functions of the form
> $$f(z)=az+b,$$
> where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a\neq 0$.

I expect any analytic automorphism of the upper half plane to be a meromorphic function of some analytic automorphisms of the complex plane. Is it correct? And how do I show the relation $ad-bc=1$?

Comment: It is standard to transform the domain to unit open disks to use the Schwarz lemma. Or you can go through kind of tedious calculations, mainly using the property $f(0), f(1), f(\infty)$ should be real numbers. For the first one, see Stein&Shakarchi Complex Analysis.

Comment: Thank you. I read the  Stein&Shakarchi's book, and find the main proof. But I can not understand a final touch, which is asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621035/simple-calculation-my-failed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose $f\in Aut(\Bbb{H})$ with some Möbius transformations to get $g = \phi \circ \rho \circ f \circ \psi \in Aut(\Bbb{D})$ such that $g(0)=0$.

Both $g(z)/z,z/g(z)$ are analytic on $\Bbb{D}$. By the maximum modulus principle $|g(z)/z|\le 1$ and $|z/g(z)|\le 1+\epsilon$.

It implies that $|g(z)/z|$ is constant $= 1$, so $g(z)/z$ is constant and $g(z)=e^{i\phi} z$. From this you got that $f$ was itself a Möbius transformation, in $PSL_2(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: Why does $g(z)=e^{i\phi}z$ imply that $f$ is a Möbius transformation?

Comment: Does it follow from the directly calculation by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621035/simple-calculation-my-failed ?

Comment: The Möbius transformations form a group, if $\phi,\rho,\psi,\phi\circ \rho \circ f\circ \psi$ are ones then so is $f$. @s.h

Comment: Are $\rho$, $\psi$, $\phi$ and $g$ Mobius? After thinking about it, but I can not understand. Mobius transformation is defined by the form $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for **real numbers** $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, right? I think their coefficients are complex, generally. I have already seen that $f$ has the form $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for some $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C}$, but I would like to show that they are all real.

Comment: @s.h Möbius transformations are with $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{C}$ (automorphisms of $\Bbb{C}\cup \infty$), it is not hard to see that for it to send $\Bbb{H}$ to itself they must be real and positive determinant.

Comment: I did it! Thank you!